# initiate class with too few arguments does not raise error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am working with some .py files and in the one there is a class which starts like this:

**file1.py**

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1="A", arg2="B", arg3="C"):
```

Then in another class it is initialised like this:

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import SomeClass

someinstance = SomeClass("Z")
```

I think I'm missing something but can't see what, and it is not so easy to run this and just look inside what is happening.

So the init method of `SomeClass` contains three keyword arguments with defaults but only one argument, without a keyword is given when the class is instantiated. Is it the default for arg1 which will be overridden by the class being instantiated like this?

Comment: So shouldn't it be instantiated like this? : `someinstance = SomeClass(arg3="Z")`

Comment: `SomeClass("Z")` means `arg1="Z", arg2="B", arg3="C"`. Whether that's what you "should" do depends on what you *want* to do.

Comment: *"the init method contains three keyword arguments"* - wrong, it contains three *parameters*. Their arguments can be supplied positionally or via keywords.

Comment: Thanks @deceze I just needed to confirm what this would do. I did not write this code, if it was me would have put that one keyword in there to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that it over-rides the first argument

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1="A", arg2="B", arg3="C"):
        self.arg1=arg1
        self.arg2=arg2
        self.arg3=arg3
        pass
someinstance = SomeClass("Z")#over rides the positional argument
someinstance.arg1
```

So should do `someinstance = SomeClass(arg3="Z")`

Comment: thanks @mad_ for the help with this which I could have checked myself if it was not so late in the day.. And someinstance.arg2 is still "B", someinstance.arg3 is still "C"

Answer (score 0):

Since, there is no `positional-argument` in your class so that's why it is giving you error. So, there are two possible solution,

First, pass `default-argument` like this,

```
someinstance = SomeClass(arg1 = "Z")
```

or

```
someinstance = SomeClass(arg2 = "Z")
```

or

```
someinstance = SomeClass(arg3 = "Z")
```

Second, solution is to make a `positional-argument` in your class,

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg, arg1="A", arg2="B", arg3="C"):
```

Now, you can pass as you did in statement,

```
someinstance = SomeClass("Z")
```

Now, it would not give you any error.